# Javascript: how to xpath string at a[integer]?

Tags: javascript

I have an xpath string like the following:

```
/html/body/table/a/img
/html/body/table/a[3]/img
```

Sometimes there is [integer], other times there isn't.

I would like a regex to split a string which works with "a" or "a[integer]".

```
string.split(/a[0-9]/);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would highly recommend an xpath-aware library (some browsers support [evaluate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/introduction_to_using_xpath_in_javascript)/XPath support from JS), but.. perhaps:

```
/\/a(?:\[\d+])?\//
```

That will match "/a/" and "/a[1234]/" (but not "a[]" or even "a/"), etc. Note that I included the "/" into the match so as to not pick up false-positives *too* easily -- wouldn't want to match "t*a*ble".